# How to customize Jekyll's url?

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I would like to use Jekyll to create a site. not a blog. Is there a way to avoid to have the creation date specified in the url and in the page's file name?

I think that the idea behind Jekyll is brilliant, but it seems too tied to blog generation content while it could be useful also in a more general use case.

Comment: Have a look at 1. [jekyll-Permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), and 2. [jekyll-configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**What the docs say:**

> You configure permalinks in your _config.yml file like this:
>
> ```
> permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html
> ```
>
> If you don’t specify any permalink setting, Jekyll uses the above pattern as the default. The permalink can also be set using a built-in permalink style:
>
> ```
> permalink: date
> ```
>
> Although you can specify a custom permalink pattern using template variables, Jekyll also provides the following built-in styles for convenience.
>
> - date = /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html
> - pretty = /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/
> - ordinal = /:categories/:year/:y_day/:title.html
> - none = /:categories/:title.html

Source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

---

**This is the basic setting I use:**

```
permalink: pretty
```

This sets pages to the pretty permalink style. Thus '/contact.md' will become '/contact/'.

**How I use it for blog posts:**

```
permalink: /blog/:title/
```

This makes sure the path contains the (sluggified) title.

**How I use it for collections:**

```
permalink: /desiredpath/:name/
```

This makes sure the path contains the filename.

Answer (score 51):

In the _config file you can change the permalink to anything you like, for example mine is

```
permalink: /blog/:title
```

As for the date you can choose your own date using the YAML front matter, again in mine i have

```
title: example
date: you can pick what ever date you want
```

Comment: +1 for having the answer without an external resource, thanks a bunch! I opted for permalink: /:title as many blogs follow this format.

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't producing blog pages, you can create files in the directory structure mapping to certain URLs. Running on localhost, if your directory has the structure

```
- _layouts/
- config.yml
- index.html
- some_other_page.html
- some_directory/
    - index.html
    - some_sub_page.html
```

You'll have content at the following locations after jekyll has processed the files:

- `0.0.0.0:4000` (index.html)
- `0.0.0.0:4000/some_other_page.html` (some_other_page.html)
- `0.0.0.0:4000/some_directory` (some_directory/index.html)
- `0.0.0.0:4000/some_directory/some_sub_page.html` (some_directory/some_sub_page.html)

[You can also use the permalink attribute on each post to set one manually, or set a different default in config.yml](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) Permalinks only have a small subset of variables available to use and need to be defined in every single file you want to put in a non-standard location.

This directory structure will automatically categorize your posts too. So you can have:

```
- some_category (defined in the yaml front matter or the _config.yml
    - index.html
    - _posts/
        - some_post.md
        - some_other_post.md
```

And posts will automatically have the category 'some category', and index.html will appear at `0.0.0.0:4000/some-category`, with the default permalink format. The category variable is available as `:category` in the permalink format string.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this old question while looking for a way to **organize jekyll pages in a `_pages` directory**, similarly to `_posts`. then access this pages without displaying the whole path in the url.

The approach that worked better for me, is to use [jekyll collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) as follows:

1 - Add a *pages* collection in `_config.yml` :

```
collections:
   pages:
     output: true
     permalink: /:path/
```

2 - create a new directory named `_pages` (it should have the same collection name, prefixed by `_`)

3 - add the pages in the `_pages` folder, as .md or .html files starting with YAML Front Matter.

eg. `/_pages/about.md` will looks like:

```
---
layout: page
---

<!-- about page content -->
```

after building that, the URL of the about page will be `<your-web-site>/about` .

Alternatively, to display a collection name, you have to define its permalink as:

```
permalink: /:collection/:path/
```